# how to give combo box itemdata as string value into visual basic 6.0

Tags: combobox, vb6

This is the code sample:

```
Set rs = Nothing
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
qry = "select maincategoryid,MCategoryName from mainCATEGORY"
rs.Open qry, Cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
If rs.EOF = False Then
    Do Until rs.EOF
        maincatddl.AddItem rs!MCategoryName, Val(rs!maincategoryid)
        catddl.ItemData(catddl.NewIndex) = Val(rs!maincategoryid)
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

It's giving me "error invalid property array index". I have string type main category id.

Comment: Should catddl be maincatddl?  Only it doesn't show where the catddl has been called with AddItem so I don't think you will have a NewIndex to use.

Comment: How does the title (adding a string as `ItemData`) relate to the question/code (error using an incorrect control name)?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible directly. However, you could create an array to hold your strings, and the ListIndex of the selected item in the ComboBox will correspond to the index of the string.

```
Dim MainCatStrings() As String
Dim CurrIndex as long
CurrIndex = 0

Set rs = Nothing
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
qry = "select maincategoryid,MCategoryName from mainCATEGORY"
rs.Open qry, Cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly

'ReDim the array to set equal to record count
ReDim MainCatStrings(rs.RecordCount)

If rs.EOF = False Then
Do Until rs.EOF

     maincatddl.AddItem rs!MCategoryName

     'Add the category ID to the string array
     MainCatStrings(CurrIndex) = rs!maincategoryid
     'Set the item data to the index value in string array
     catddl.ItemData(catddl.NewIndex) = CurrIndex

     CurrIndex = CurrIndex + 1

rs.MoveNext
Loop
End If
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things wrong here. First of all, this bit of code isn't very reusable, since you are trying to add the contents of the recordset into the Combo Box, but what if you wanted to run this code again - you would get a whole load of duplicates. So really, you need to clear the contents of the Combo Box, e.g.
`maincatddl.Clear`

```
Set rs = Nothing
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
qry = "select maincategoryid,MCategoryName from mainCATEGORY"
rs.Open qry, Cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
If rs.EOF = False Then
    Do Until rs.EOF
```

... but which one? Normally, when you see .`AddItem()`, the next line is .`ItemData`(.`NewIndex`). But you have two different names:, `maincatddl` and `catddl`.

```
        maincatddl.AddItem rs!MCategoryName, Val(rs!maincategoryid)
        catddl.ItemData(catddl.NewIndex) = Val(rs!maincategoryid)
```

The balance of probabilities is that you intended `maincatddl` for the second line. You have obviously misunderstood the second parameter of the `AddItem()` method, `Index`. It looks as if you think this is meant to be user-defined integer, like the value of the `ItemData()` property. But `Index` is actually the position you want the new item to appear in the list. It may seem to work, assuming that `Index` is in the range (0 to .ListCount).

Unless you want the item to appear in a certain order, this line should be ammended to:
`maincatddl.AddItem rs!MCategoryName`

`maincatddl.ItemData(maincatddl.NewIndex) = Val(rs!maincategoryid)`

And incidentally, if you are using a lot of pairs of lines following this pattern, I would recommend you write a procedure to encapsulate this behaviour.

```
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally ItemData of ComboBox and ListBox must be only Long Positive Or 0.
The simplest way for add other types of ItemData is using Collection.
In sample below ItemData of ComboBox and ListBox can have following types:
Long negative, String, any VB6 control (Image as sample ), any Object of VB6 (Form as sample).
[Source.](http://www.filedropper.com/boxitemdataclass)

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [Codejock](http://www.codejock.com/) controls for VB6. I use them for years in my company.

The ListBox and ComboBox ItemData and Tag properties from them are Variant and then they support strings as well as objects.